# New to blender: my model turned dark grey after clicking something on accident

Tags: modeling

I clicked something on accident and now my model looks like this and it's hard to see: [image: model turned dark gray plz help]

edit: nvrmind I think I fixed it. click the shaded moon/circle looking things in the upper right hand corner of the viewport.